# How do I use this for checking for 3 numbers instead of just 2? c#

Tags: c#

This loop is for checking if there are two of the same value in an `array` My questions is how I can do this for checking if 3 values are the same.

Please see my code:

```
public static bool ContainsDuplicates(int[] a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.Length; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] == a[j]) return true;
        }
    }
return false;
}
```

Comment: Just count equals then if count become larger than or equal  to 3 then return ;).

Comment: Or a Linq way is `a.GroupBy(g => g).Any(c => c.Count() > 2)` ;).

Comment: The thing is that I want diffrent things to happen when diffrent numbers are the same.

Answer (score 0):

For search x times value in list do the next.

```
public static bool ContainsDuplicates(int[] a)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        count = 0;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.Length; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] == a[j])
            {
                count++;
            }

        }
        //Your value here
        if (count >= 3)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could do this as already pointed out. One way would be to simply extend your current pattern and add another `for`.

```
public static bool ContainsDuplicates(int[] a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.Length; j++)
        {
            for(int k = j + 1; k < a.Length; k++)
                if (a[i] == a[j] && a[j] == a[k]) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

The cleaner/better looking way, however, would be the suggestion to use `Linq` mentioned by shA.t.

```
a.GroupBy(g => g).Any(c => c.Count() > 2)
```

If they want to add this as an answer I'll removed it from mine, just figured I would include it for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `GroupBy` and `Count` which can be easily *generalized* for any `duplicatesAtLeast` duplicates:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  public static bool ContainsDuplicates(int[] a, int duplicatesAtLeast = 3) {
    if (null == a)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("a");

    if (duplicatesAtLeast <= 0)
      return a.Any();
    else if (duplicatesAtLeast > a.Length)
      return false;

    return a
      .GroupBy(item => item)
      .Any(chunk => chunk.Count() >= duplicatesAtLeast); 
  }
```